# Correct site to ask questions about statistics

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about why a certain statistic is calculated the way it is. There are certain constants present in the formula, and I'm not sure I understand why those specific values are used. Would this be appropriate for the math Stack Exchange, or is there a specific place to ask questions about statistics?

**Edit:**
[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) seems the most appropriate, but none of the questions look like the one I'm asking. It seems to be computer science focused. Should I ask there anyway?

Comment: In fact programming questions are off-topic on CV although many questions and answers do contain illustrative code.

Comment: Statistics is a significant branch of Mathematics, and construction of statistical models, which seems central to the question, is a significant part of Statistics in that sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a good bet.  From the site:

> Q&A for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization.

[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) also might be a good place for your question - they have a [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag there, and your question looks more mathematical, less computer-sciencey.  From the [tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/statistics/info):

> Mathematical statistics is the study of statistics from a mathematical standpoint, using probability theory and other branches of mathematics such as linear algebra and analysis.

As your question has more of that than the previous quote, it might be the more appropriate site.

**EDIT:**

Cross Validated also has a tag for [mathematical statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-statistics).  From the [tag info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematical-statistics/info):

> Mathematical theory of statistics, concerned with formal definitions and general results.
> Mathematical statistics is the study of statistics from a mathematical point of view, concerned with formal definitions and general results.

So your question looks equally well suited for both sites.

Comment: NB Cross Validated has a tag for Mathematical Statistics, "the study of statistics from a mathematical point of view, concerned with formal definitions and general results."  The scopes of the Maths & of the Statistics sites overlap here, & this question is as likely to obtain a good answer on one as on the other.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica thank you for pointing that out!  I have seen the MS tag on Cross Validated, but didn't think to mention it.